# Accessing a variable of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

What is this code doing? I'm just trying to understand the library I'm using (brace). It looks like it's setting some variables for a function? I'm having a hard time even googling this because I'm not sure what it's called.

```
var define = function(module, deps, payload) {
    if (typeof module !== "string") {
        if (define.original)
            define.original.apply(this, arguments);
        else {
            console.error("dropping module because define wasn\'t a string.");
            console.trace();
        }
        return;
    }
    if (arguments.length == 2)
        payload = deps;
    if (!define.modules[module]) {
        define.payloads[module] = payload;
        define.modules[module] = null;
    }
};

define.modules = {};
define.payloads = {};
```

Comment: It's setting properties of the function, not variables. A function is also an object.

Comment: oh I see why would it ever do this outside of the function though?

Comment: So that it doesn't have to check whether the properties are initialized every time you call the function.

Comment: `define` is hoisted, so its available inside function. Based on code, following is the assumption. You can either pass a module(*object/function*) or string. If you pass string, you need `define` to have a property `original` through which the module is loaded.

Comment: I tried var print = function() { console.log(a); }; print.a = 123; and I thought it would print 123 but instead it throws an error, why is that?

Comment: Ah nevermind it needs to be print.a, thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

The function is using properties of the function object instead of defining global variables to hold its state.

The assignments at the end just initialize the `modules` and `payloads` properties. Otherwise, the function would have to check for this every time, with something like:

```
if (!define.modules) {
    define.modules = {};
    define.payloads = {};
}
```

before the code that adds the new entries to those objects. But since this only needs to be done one, it's wasteful to check it every time.